# Netbeans понимает scss, но не до конца?

Tags: sass, netbeans, scss

Вводные: NetBeans 11.3 @ Windows10, Sass установлен, настроен и все работет.

Есть .scss файл с такой конструкцией:

```
.input-group-btn:last-child > {
  .btn, .btn-group {
    margin-left: 0;
  }
}
```

Для scss это нормально, файл компилится без проблем, НО! подсветка синтаксиса ругается на вот эту часть "> {", хотя все остальное scss-добро подсвечивается корректно.

И все бы ничего, если бы подсветка синтаксиса не прекращала работать после некоторого кол-ва ошибок - в итоге у меня пол-файла без подсветки и возможности автокомплита.

Вопрос - с чего бы это, и как это можно вылечить? Установкой какого-либо плагина для scss? обновлением данных о синтаксисе языка? или это баг в ядре IDE, и с этим вообще ничего не поделаешь?

Заранее спасибо за любую подсказку.